# How do I find out what browsers support 'disabled' property?

Tags: dom, cross-browser

Basically, I want to have a good understanding on what browsers support `element.disabled = true` as opposed to `element.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')`.

I can solve things with the latter syntax or with jQuery or with something else, but I am just interested about where to look when I get the same question next time.

Comment: Check out the [Quirksmode compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html).

Comment: I do not see `disabled` property in any of these, am I looking not well enough?

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax for disabled is `disabled='disabled'` all modern browsers should behave correctly given this.

Comment: But http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html says that it is a boolean property (when viewed from DOM/JS)?

Comment: that may be what it says but empirically using true or false never seems to work across browsers and disabled does!

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I want to know -- where to look for such data across browsers?

Comment: I haven't seen any list. I always use `disabled='disabled'` as it always works